# How to invert Lerp function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

```
float lerp(float v0, float v1, float t) {
  return (1 - t) * v0 + t * v1;
}
```

In my situation I know the result and it is always 0, I know *v0* and I know *v1*. What I want to caculate, is *t*. I tried to break it up like `(1 - t) * v0 + t * v1 = 0` and bring *t* out, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 
$$  (1-t)v_0 + t v_1 = \mathrm{lerp}  $$
we have
$$  v_0 - t v_0 + t v_1 = \mathrm{lerp}  $$
$$  v_0 - t (v_0 + v_1) = \mathrm{lerp}  $$
$$  v_0 - \mathrm{lerp} = t (v_0 + v_1)  $$
$$  \frac{v_0 - \mathrm{lerp}}{v_0 + v_1} = t  $$

When $\mathrm{lerp} = 0$, this simplifies to 
$$  t_{\mathrm{lerp} = 0} = \frac{v_0}{v_0 + v_1}  \text{.}  $$